# Are there security issues with Fusion Tables

Tags: google-maps, security, google-fusion-tables

I'm contemplating using google fusion tables rather than using a mysql database to populate a google map. The data that I'm displaying is somewhat proprietary, not top secret, but I'm concerned that if I use a fusion table, people will be able to scrape the the Data, or just grab it directly from the fusion table. I may be misunderstanding how this works, but it seems from some the the threads I read, there is really no way to protect your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual the answer is: it depends.

If you want to use the Google Maps feature "FusionTableLayer" to display the data, you'll have to be a Google Maps Premier customer to be able to display data from private tables. For "normal" users, this is only possible with public tables.

But when you access the data via the API you can easily just select and display the data you want. But as long as you keep the table private there is no way of getting the original data.

Last but not least you have to trust Google ;-)